# External Log files from Ant

Tags: ant

I have configured Log4j in my project and that is invoked by an Ant task.

I want the Ant logs as well as project logs to be written to single file along with timestamps.

Could you let me know how to take care of this in Ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Ant in such a way that it's logging is via Log4j, there's an example in the Ant [*Listeners & Loggers*](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#Log4jListener) page:

```
ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener
```

but see the Ant documentation for proper details, how to ensure log4j.properties etc. are found.